# How to Execute Selenium Selenium Test Cases based on Excel Flag. If Yes only then run the test cases using JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, data-driven-tests

Flag Yes only should be run. Else part won't execute but if the condition is failed, else is getting passed.

```
if(data.get(Flag).equals("Yes}) && data.get(TC_Name).equals("TC_Name")){

......

}else{
 .....
}
```

Comment: Is this statement correct? - if(data.get(Flag).equals("Yes") && data.get(TC_Name).equals("Login")) - you have to use double quotes instead of }.

Comment: Your condition is composite. Make sure you have expected result after `&&`. Use debugging capabilities of your IDE.

Comment: if(data.get(Flag).equals("Yes") && data.get(TC_Name).equals("Login")) These are Matching Strings, Getting  data from excel which are all Flag Yes with Testcase name will execute the script